# What does a request to a DNS server look like?

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I'm trying to learn how internet works. I have some knowledge about HTTP requests, and now I am wondering, what does a request to DNS server look like? For instance, if I wanted to get a list of movies from a random site, by a HTTP request, it would be something like this:

`GET http://movies.com/api/movies`

plus, maybe some metadata too.
And in response, I would get some headers and, let's say, a JSON body with a list of movies.

But when talking about DNS servers, how do requests look like? Are they GET requests too? Like this:

`GET http://123.456.789.101/domain=google.com` (`123.456.789.101` is my ISP's IP address)

with a response of "142.250.203.206"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) uses a binary datagram layout, rather than text like HTTP/FTP/Etc.

See here for details of the application-layer datagram layout:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#DNS_message_format

Comment: An easier way to see for yourself is to capture some packets and inspect them using Wireshark.

Comment: For some reason, I didn't see a duplicate question when I was writing this one, but here it is: https://serverfault.com/questions/173187/what-does-a-dns-request-look-like
I will probably close this question, since it's almost identical.